# Quel est le sens de cette phrase en anglais?

Tags: sens, traduction

Salut!

Je suis en train de lire un livre (Alice au Canada) et il y a une phrase qui dit:

*Il faut nous promettre de ne pas nous réserver autant d'émotions*

Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire?

[image]

Comment: Dans quel livre se trouve cette phrase ? Pourriez-vous ajouter au texte de votre question une ou deux des phrases qui précèdent et vérifier l'orthographe ? Il y a des fautes d'orthographe ; sont-elles dans le texte ?

Comment: J'ai corrigé mon erreur. C'est dans le livre "Alice au Canada". Merci!

Comment: You have to promise us not to harbor so many feelings towards us.

Comment: Hi @némésie-t-île I have added the text, it is on page 185. It is about 3 girls who were guests to Mme Donnelly in a city in Canada where they had so many adventures and incidents.

Comment: This helped me to find the original English text. I have updated my answer with it.

Comment: Thank you so it's settled then. @jlliagre hahah j'ai cherché en masse mais j'étais pris avec des documents sans _ocr_ et pas de preview sur _books_ etc et il n'y avait que 20 chapitres dans ma version donc j'étais perplexe. En passant ta phrase marche aussi mais je sais pas comment formuler pcq. 2 verbes avoir biz., c'est davantage _to have (something) in store (for someone)_, poss.. « But please swear you won't have so much excitement in store for us next time over », mais je trouve que ça sonne un peu biz. encore je sais pas si on peut dire _hold_ plutôt que _have_ ici blabla. Lambie ? Entk.

Comment: Cette question demande ce que veut dire quelque chose (en français, donc pas une demande de traduction). Pas de problème mais elle devrait être plus précise sur ce qui n'est pas compris ou émettre une hypothèse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the sentence actually reads:

> *Il faut nous promettre de ne pas nous réserver autant d'émotions.*

The meaning is something like:

> You have to promise not to keep so many surprises (thrills?) for us.

or ([perhaps](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45513/quel-est-le-sens-de-cette-phrase-en-anglais#comment92789_45515)?), as suggested by @Lambie

> You have to promise us not to harbor so many feelings towards us.

Edit: *[Alice in Canada](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_au_Canada)* being a translation of [The message in the Hollow Oak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Message_in_the_Hollow_Oak), the original sentence reads:

> **But you must promise not to provide us with so much excitement.**

Here is an excerpt from the original book:

[image]

Comment: This makes sense in the context of the book . Merci!

Comment: Il y a possiblement confusion, il faut voir le texte en français. _Harbor_ signifie qu'on a interprété la phrase comme _entretenir_ (du ressentiment) alors que je lis la phrase comme _faire vivre_. En d'autres mots la phrase de Lambie n'est possiblement pas une version plus idiomatique de ta phrase, elle a carrément un sens différent il me semble...